# Inject a flash on specific exception

Tags: symfony, exception, controller

I'm extending a custom exception for all my handled "application errors"

```
abstract class AbstractApplicationException extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct(array $context = array())
    {
        $this->context = $context;
        parent::__construct('exceptions.'.lcfirst(self::classname()));
    }
}
```

And I use `messages.xx.yml` to describe the error to the user

```
exceptions:
    incompatibleSettings: Vos réglages ne sont pas compatibles
```

I'd like to automatically inject a flash with the translated message on exception (of kind `AbstractApplicationException`) so I don't have to do it on all my controllers

```
public myControllerAction()
    try {
        $someService->someFunction();
    } catch (AbstractApplicationException $e) {
        $flashBag->add('error',
            $this->get('translator')->trans(
                $e->getMessage(), $e->getContext()
            )
        );
    }
    $this->render('related_template.html.twig');
}
```

I know how to redirect the user with a listener, but I actually want the user to land on the specific action reponse, **only with a flash injected**.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an Exception [listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html):

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\AcmeExceptionListener
        arguments: [@router, @session]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Then set flash message and redirect user to the action you want, which will render it:

```
class AcmeExceptionListener
{
    /**
     * @var UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var SessionInterface
     */        
    private $session;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->router  = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if ($exception instanceof YourExceptionType) {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', $exception->getMessage());

            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('your_route')));    
        }
    }
}
```

**Be careful with this though**: if during exception handling you again throw YourExceptionType, you will end up having infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this exception listener code is interesting. I finally used a trait to add a try/catcher shortcut so I can continue the execution of my controllers (ie returning the related specific response). I'm going to add my solution here

Answer (score 1):

I finally used a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to be able to continue the execution of my controllers with the flash injected.

```
/**
 * Class ControllerTrait
 * @requirement The using class must be containerAware
 */
trait ControllerTrait {
    public function injectExceptionFlash(AbstractApplicationException $e) {
        if (!isset($this->container)) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf('You must containerAware to use %s',
                __TRAIT__
            ));
        }
        $flashBag = $this->container->get('session')->getFlashBag();
        $flashBag->add('error',
            $this->container->get('translator')->trans(
                $e->getMessage(), $e->getContext()
            )
        );
    }

    public function tryFlash($lambda) {
        try {
            $lambda();
        } catch (AbstractApplicationException $e) {
            $this->injectExceptionFlash($e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I use it from my controllers

```
use ControllerTrait;

public myControllerAction()
    $this->tryFlash(function () (use $someParam) {
        $someService->someFunction($someParam);
    });
    $this->render('related_template.html.twig');
}
```

`tryFlash()` is a shortcut using a [lambda function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to do the try/catch/flash jobs

Don't hesitate to tell me if there is a bad practice somewhere